# How to get duplicate elements in array list using guava predicates

Tags: java, guava, predicates, google-guava-cache

I have a array with set of elements. I need to find the duplicate elements in that array by comparing particular field using guava predicated in java.

**For example:** 
I have an arraylist with set of employees details. I need to find details of employees with same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Guava [Multimaps.index](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Employee> byName = 
  Multimaps.index(employees, new Function<Employee, String>(){
      @Override
      public String apply(Employee e) {
          return e.getName();
      } 
  });
```

In Java 8:

```
Map<Department, List<Employee>> byName = 
    employees.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName))
```

---

Regarding your comment, it seems that you want to filter the list to keep only employees with a specific name.

So using Guava:

```
List<Employee> employees = // ...
Collection<Employee> filtered = 
    Collections2.filter(employees, new Predicate<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Employee e) {
            return e.getName().equals("John Doe");
        }
    });
// if you want a List:
List<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(filtered);
```

Using Java 8:

```
List<Employee> filteredList = employees.stream()
                                       .filter(e -> e.getName().equals("John Doe"))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What about advertising Java8 lambda expressions here?

Comment: @hege_hegedus You got it

Comment: That's even better! I just thought about `Multimaps.index(employees, e -> e.getName())` :)

Comment: The above code is just grouping the list based on name. What i need is a List of names that have more than once in that LIST

Comment: @Krieger Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: @ Jean Logeart For example, there is a List of employee details objects . I need to filter employee details from that list by empoyees with same name

Comment: You mean with a specific name, like filtering the list? What my example does is that it groups all employees with the same name.

Comment: Yes, i need filtered list. not grouped list with same name. Is there any way to do in Guava?

Comment: @ Jean Logeart Thanks for answer. Also i need a list with same name employees, but the problem here is i dont know the name. I just need list of employees with name occurs more than once from exsisting List.